# Maven module, debugging on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm working with a maven project and I have created few modules with this structure:

- Parent

  - Module A (generates war and jar, default packaging is war)
  - Module B (generates war and depends on module A jar)
  - Module C (generates war and depends on module A jar)

For debug time I have an eclipse/tomcat configuration, but when I need to debug Module B, the jar from Module A will not load inside the lib folder.

Running maven normally will do the job, but I need to run the module using eclipse in order to perform the debug task.

Is there a way to tell eclipse or to perform this simply task?

*Edit*: This is a legacy project, so when moving to maven this was the structure.

Comment: Split module A so that the jar is separate.

Comment: @JFMeier I can't do that, this module has the core for the others but also is an application. Another idea?

Comment: Pretty sure @JFMeier is spot on. Each module should create one artifact (war, jar, pom, etc). The best solution would be create a jar module and then war modules that include the jar as dependencies.
That said, for debugging, if you're using maven-tomcat or cargo plugins to launch your war files, you can easily configure these for remote debugging and connect the eclipse via a remote application debug configuration.

Comment: @MichaelPeacock I changed the packaging in Module A as jar but nothing happened, how should I tell eclipse to take that build output in Module B?

Comment: Maven doesn't add the output of module A into module b. Instead, you run mvn clean install to build the project. This will install all the separate modules into your local Maven repository. If Module A generates a jar file, then using install will add it to the local maven repo so other modules in the same project can find and use that jar during dependency resolution.

Comment: @MichaelPeacock that's right, this is the normal life cicle I have, but will only work if I call _maven install_ directly. Instead I'm only running the server in debug mode, that's why I asked originally if I could try a different option using the IDE

Comment: I've had better luck using the tomcat7-maven-plugin in eclipse, and using mvn clean instal tomcat7:run to launch the war in an embedded tomcat container. See this for more info - http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat7-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html  Again, remote debugging is supported with the proper configuration.